# Flutter : BUILD FAILED in 11s Unhandled exception: FileSystemException: writeFrom failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle

I'm new to flutter and mobile development. I was working on the app and everything was working fine. After a few hours I try to run my app on the device and I get the following error:

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Problems writing to Binary store in /private/var/folders/k9/g_78rhy13m968yn0yg9v6jb40000gn/T/gradle16554077359029727541.bin (exist: true)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: writeFrom failed, path = '/var/folders/k9/g_78rhy13m968yn0yg9v6jb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.1owVKQ/flutter_tool.i2A2YL/app.dill' 
(OS Error: No space left on device, errno = 28)
#0      _RandomAccessFile.writeFrom.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:852:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _FileStreamConsumer.addStream.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:184:21)

<asynchronous suspension>
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the main problem was that my computer had less disk space available. that's why the error says `(OS: No space left on device, errno=28)`

I just freed up some space on my disk and everything works fine.

Comment: yes correct i was confused because i saw that my phone that i am trying to run the app on had enough storage

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the temporary folder will work

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Or you can increase available space in tmp by doing remount instead of "rm -rf" :

```
mount -o remount,size=8G,noatime /tmp
```

Comment: Thanks. 

It may work but I found that the main problem was that my computer had less disk space available.

Comment: Ok , Happy coding :) @GedFlod